# How do I show that this integral $\int _0^1 x\sqrt {1+\frac {1} {x^4}} dx$ does not converge?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Shouldn’t I find a function whose integral over the interval does not converges either and is always less than $\;\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}\;$ when close to zero so that the first integral is also divergent? I’m afraid I’m only familiarized with this approach.

Comment: Set $x^2=\cot y$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
 x\sqrt {1+\frac {1} {x^4}}= \frac1{x}\sqrt {x^4+1}>\frac1x
$$ thus the given integral is *divergent*.

Answer (score 0):

Away from zero,
there is no promlem.

As you approach zero,
the function behaves like
$x/x^2 =1/x$
and the integral of this
(being $\ln(x)$)
diverges as
$x \to 0$.